# Copying hyperlinks in Irssi?

Tags: linux, irssi

I'm using a tiling window manager so I find it convenient to use terminal apps as much as possible. So, Irssi is my IRC client. The only problem here is that if someone references a website in IRC, I have to bring my web browser (Konqueror) over to that workspace, and then type the URL in by hand.

So, my question: Is there an easy way to copy a URL in Irssi (I'm using mrxvt if that helps)? I'd love to be able to do it with key commands, but using the mouse would be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's easy: Just select the URL in irssi, move to the workspace with your web browser, and middle click on the address bar to paste the selection.

Answer (score 0):

You can start irssi from screen, which provides a copy mode. See my [other answer over there](https://superuser.com/questions/176015/copying-urls-in-irssi/215239#215239).