# Using irssi, is there a way to copy URLs so I can open them in elinks?

Tags: irssi

I know there is another question about this (hopefully the one I saw is the only one) but mine is a little different.

Using irssi from the command line (without X), is there a way to copy and paste URLs so I can open them in elinks?

Answer (score 1):

You could use screen to run irssi in. This would allow you to use screen's copy mode (triggered using Ctrl-A Esc).

See http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/screen_11.html for reference.

I've also found the following script, which allows to open the last URL in a browser:
http://scripts.irssi.org/html/urlgrab.pl.html